# Python - import instance of class from module

Tags: python, class, scrapy

I have created this class with `parse()`:

```
class PitchforkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "pitchfork_reissues"
    allowed_domains = ["pitchfork.com"]
    #creates objects for each URL listed here
    start_urls = [
                    "http://pitchfork.com/reviews/best/reissues/?page=1",
                    "http://pitchfork.com/reviews/best/reissues/?page=2",
                    "http://pitchfork.com/reviews/best/reissues/?page=3",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="album-artist"]'):
            item = PitchforkItem()
            item['artist'] = sel.xpath('//ul[@class="artist-list"]/li/text()').extract()
            item['reissue'] = sel.xpath('//h2[@class="title"]/text()').extract()

        return item
```

then I import the `module` where the `class` belongs:

```
from blogs.spiders.pitchfork_reissues_feed import *
```

and try to call `parse()` in another context:

```
def reissues(self):

    pitchfork_reissues = PitchforkSpider()
    reissues = pitchfork_reissues.parse('response')
    print (reissues)
```

but I get the following error:

```
pitchfork_reissues.parse('response')
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/Documents/Code/Soup/Apps/myapp/blogs/blogs/spiders/pitchfork_reissues_feed.py", line 21, in parse
    for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="album-artist"]'):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'xpath'
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `parse` with a string literal:

```
reissues = pitchfork_reissues.parse('response')
```

I guess that should be a variable name? Like so:

```
reissues = pitchfork_reissues.parse(response)
```

**Edit**

A Spider's `parse` method requires an instance of `scrapy.http.Response` as it's first argument, not a string literal that contains the word 'response'.

I haven't used Scrapy myself, so I only know what I read in the documentation, but apparently such a Response instance is usually created by a 'Downloader'.

It seems that you're trying to call your Spider's `parse` method outside of Scrapy's usual workflow. In that case I think you're responsible for creating such a Response and passing it to your Spider when calling it's `parse` method.

Comment: that gives me the following traceback:  `reissues = pitchfork_reissues.parse(response)
NameError: global name 'response' is not defined`

Comment: Well you would need a scrapy.http.Response instance, which appearantly is "downloaded (by the Downloader)". See [the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#response-objects) :)